NavigationStack - NavigationLink doesn't work
In the MainView, I have this below NaviationStack:
.navigationDestination(for: String.self){ selection in
    
    if(selection == "login"){
        Login()
    }else if(selection == "register"){
        CreateAccount()
    }
}

In a sub view, I have this:
NavigationLink(value: "login"){
    Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .frame(height: profImgSize)
        .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(named: "IconColor")!))
}

When I tap on it, I get:

Note: Links search for destinations in any surrounding NavigationStack, then within the same column of a NavigationSplitView.
A NavigationLink is presenting a value of type “String” but there is no matching navigationDestination declaration visible from the location of the link. The link cannot be activated.

When I create a minimal example, then it works and when I would post all the code here then it would be way too much. What could be the problem here?

Remove code from your non-working version until you get a [mre]

This is very time consuming, I hoped someone already had this situation and knows what's the problem. I will do that in case I don't get an answer soon.

The problem is already described in the error message. Why it's happening in your case is speculative unless you include your code.

Swift error messages are generally useless horse sh**, if you understand it then why don't you explain?

"Links search for destinations in any surrounding NavigationStack, then within the same column of a NavigationSplitView." Is this even proper english? What the hell is this?

When you say "I have this below NaviationStack" do you mean it's outside NavigationStack? If you look at the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationstack), it needs to be inside, which the error is telling you ("surrounding NavigationStack"). But, again, speculative, since I don't have your code.

Ok it works now xD Thank you very much! I'll accept when you post an answer.

Your navigationDestination is outside of a NavigationStack. The error message tells you that when it says:

Links search for destinations in any surrounding NavigationStack

When looking at the documentation, you can see that navigationDestination should go inside the NavigationStack:
NavigationStack {
    List(parks) { park in
        NavigationLink(park.name, value: park)
    }
    .navigationDestination(for: Park.self) { park in
        ParkDetails(park: park)
    }
}

